# Dialog personalizada

Tags: android, android-layout

Bom dia,
Fiz uma Dialog personalizada usando um fragment para personaliza-la, mas preciso fazer com que ela tenha os cantos arredondados.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_modal_dialog">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/Title_white"
        android:text="Atenção"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="Você tem mais de 18 anos?"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:id="@+id/btn_no"
            android:text="Não"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/button_effect_secondary_dialog"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:id="@+id/btn_yes"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Sim"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/button_effect_primary_dialog" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: pode adicionaro **@drawable/shape_modal_dialog** ? Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um arquivo no qual definirá como *background*. Por exemplos `borda_redonda.xml`, colocando-o dentro do seu `drawable`, lembrando que cada canto pode ser definido com tamanhos diferentes. As bordas são definidas usando `<corners>` propondo para cada canto, um tamanho diferente usando `Radius`. Para inserir uma cor do fundo use o parâmetro `<solid>` definindo `android:color` sendo igual a cor em hexadecimal. No exemplo logo abaixo foi definido uma cor preta com transparência `#E6`. Veja:

**borda_redonda.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#E6000000" />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Depois é só configurar o atributo `android:background` do seu `RelativeLayout`. Veja abaixo:

**meu_dialogo.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/borda_redonda">

    <!-- conteúdo -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu arquivo **shape_modal_dialog**, você precisa adicionar o seguinte campo:

```
<corners
     android:radius="6dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Muito obrigado pela ajuda, consegui resolver com isso:

```
dialogPay.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
    new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```